# vue.js v-model with array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-model

i have a dynamic number of fields on the page and trying to bind an array to control changes on the page, but got stuck with v-model

Here is how i'm building a page (minimal example to reproduce):

```
<b-form-group v-for="(element, i) in banners" :key="i"  :label="'Banner ' + (i+1)">
  <input
    type="text" class="form-control"
    :v-model="element.name"
    :name="'bannername[' + i + ']'">
  <img :src="element.image" class="banner-preview">
</b-form-group>
```

This way i'm getting proper src for the img, but input is empty all the time. (checked the data by changing v-model to value, everything is fine, but i need to bind it here)

Comment: Did you try using `v-model` instead of `:v-model`?

Comment: damn, looks like i need a cup of coffee

Comment: @AlbertoRivera feel free to post it as an answer for my dumb question >.<

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `v-model` instead of `:v-model`